# Cocos2d-x: possible to use HTML (UIWebView)?

Tags: android, html, uiwebview, cocos2d-x

I'm trying out `cocos2d-x` and got to the point where I can build the Javascript samples for Android and run them inside a browser as well.

Now I want to create my own game, but coming from a HTML background, I'd rather use HTML tags with CSS than use Javascript to setup the user interface.

I've read about UIWebView which can display HTML-pages in an app, but I was wondering if anyone has ever done this in combination with Cocos2D-x ?  And could this be transparent, to overlay a normal cocos2d-x screen in the app then?
If so, how could this be done?

Comment: have you posted this question on their forums or something similar? An interesting question but this might be closed because it seems very specific to that particular platform/sdk.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [CCXWebview](https://github.com/go3k/CCXWebview) for that with Cocos2d-x. This extension is based on Cocos2d-x 2.0.4 and it seems to work also on Cocos2d-x 2.x with some modification.

However, if you want to use Cocos2d-x 3.0 for Android, you cannot use it because Cocos2d-x 3.0 uses NativeActivity, thus you cannot combine Android WebView on the Cocos2d-x screen.

**EDITED**

> only problem is that I have little knowledge of Java or C++
>   ... It would take me years to figure the Java and C++ things out :)

So why are you sticking to use Cocos2d-x??? Why don't you use Cocos2d-html5? It has same functionality as Cocos2d-x JavaScript binding and it uses HTML5 Canvas, so you can use DOM with it.

https://twitter.com/hyperandroid/status/311534580962295809 :

> Cocoonjs can run Cocos2d-html5 games too.

Comment: Thanks, only problem is that I have little knowledge of Java or C++. It took me weeks to just be able to compile the Javascript-binding examples in both Eclipse and Intellij IDEA (on Windows). It would take me years to figure the Java and C++ things out :)

Comment: Well, the ultimate goal is to create apps for Android and iOS, and as far as I understand it, using DOM will not be possible when compiling into an app. I have looked at CocoonJS, but I don't like their compile-in-the-cloud-only strategy, and their pricing is also uncertain...  So I was hoping for an 'easy' hybrid solution with cocos2d-x...

Comment: CCXWebview is one of the most easist hybrid solution with cocos2d-x.

Comment: excuse me, is CCXWebview compatible with Cocos2dx JS?