# webview on cocos2d-x 3.0

Tags: android, webview, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

i want to show webview in my game.i found a example here.it works fine on cocos2d-x 2.2.0.
but when i'm doing same thing in cocos2d-x 3.0 beta2,the webview can't show.
http://blog.csdn.net/jackystudio/article/details/17576995

i noticed that cocos2d-x 3.0 using NativeActivity, is it causing webview can't show?
[Cocos2d-x: possible to use HTML (UIWebView)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20886808/cocos2d-x-possible-to-use-html-uiwebview)

any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.
thx.

Answer (score 0):

current release of cpp *Cocos2d-x v3.2rc0* use Android Activity not NativeActivity. So you can try your linked example from *2.2.0* version. Maybe you get some errors about opengl context or handler - so **be sure that your java code will be executed GUI thread** - runOnUiThread.

Here is the little sample how to do it, in another way:
[ANDROID:How to open web page in class extends CCLayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10281446/androidhow-to-open-web-page-in-class-extends-cclayer)

Main point is to run android gui thread:

```
Handler handler = HomeMenu.getHandler();
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {...
```